# When I run npm start, my main output file isn't created

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

I'm building a react app with webpack and when I run npm start, I get a success message with no errors but I don't see the main output file that it's supposed to create isn't made.

I'm using webpack and here is my webpack.config.js file

```
module.exports = {
  entry: './src/app.jsx',
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'main.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel'
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './'
  }
};
```

Not sure what else is necessary to provide for help with this issue but I'd be happy to provide it.  All of my jsx code is inside an src/ folder in the root directory.

Comment: did you run npm install ?

Comment: yes, and everything seemed to install fine

Comment: You should be running `node file_that_starts_server`

Comment: Sorry if I'm misunderstanding the advice, but I'm new to using node so I'm not quite sure what you mean.  This code right now is up on a server, what kind of other files/servers do I need to run?  Any links you could point me to?

Comment: So I just checked and as part of `npm start` it does run `node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js`  Is this what you're referring to?  And if so, it looks like it's running every time `npm start` is called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are launching with `npm start` is the webpack-dev-server (as you specified in the comments). This won't create any file on your hard drive. By default, it will open a server on http://localhost:8080/ serving your bundle (everything staying in memory).

If you want to build your bundle (make the `main.js` file on your hardrive), so that you could distribute it on production, you need to run `./node_modules/.bin/webpack --progress`.

Comment: Thanks!  `main.js` is bundling, now :)